# Divide UITableView into fixed number of cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I created a UIViewController which has a header and contains a UITableView. Now I want to divide the whole height of the UITableView between 6 cells. I tried it with `tableView.frame.size.height` and then set the `tableView.rowHeight = tableViewHeight / 6`. But when I launch the application, there is still some space left on the bottom of the table view.
Is there another way?

Comment: I assume you're using autolayout?

Comment: Yeah, I added 4 constraints to the table, so it fills the whole space.

Comment: Just a quick thought, if you're accessing `tableView.frame.size.height` in `viewDidLoad:`, then it might not return the height you're expecting, as the views have not been laid out yet.

Comment: Wait--do you want 6 or 7 cells? The title doesn't match the question.

Comment: ah sorry, actually 6. But it seems somebody already fixed it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would recommend returning the cell height from the `tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` delegate method like so:

```
let numOfRows = 7

...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return numOfRows
}

...

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    return tableView.frame.size.height / CGFloat(numOfRows)
}
```

With that method, you're given direct access to your `tableView` where you can divide its height by the number of rows you want. Return that value to set the tableView's row height.